# Abaqus on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, abaqus

Install Abaqus CAE on ubuntu, after selecting install directory and proceed, got following error

```
Creating child process failed. Log ID is 0001

Action LaunchAPpAction from freature CODE\Linux_a64\SIMCAE_TP.PRD FAILED.
Action ID: verifyNoDeltaInstall
```

Anybody know how to solve this problem? Thx

Comment: How did you install Abaqus?

Comment: Don't understand. Abaqus has the linux version @OrtomalaLokni

Comment: This maybe could help you : http://home.iitk.ac.in/~saiwal/linux/install-abaqus-ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Solved by installing glibc.

On RHEL6

```
sudo yum install glibc.i686
```

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 16.04 with Abaqus2017, I installed

```
sudo apt-get install lsb-core
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62
```

to get rid of this error

Answer (score 0):

I had to install perl on Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.5 (Ootpa) to fix it:

```
yum install perl
```